# Why doesn't replacing paragraph content using method of ignoring of junk artifacts work?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace the content of second `p` using `childNodes` array and ignoring junk artifacts.When i change the content of the paragraph using `d.childNodes[i].innerHTMl = "paragraph4"` and display the resualt,`"paragraph4"` is displayed but why does not it change in the document?

```
   <div id="myDiv">
     <p>pargraph1</p>
     <p>paragraph2</p>
     <p>paragraph3</p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var d=document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var pCounter=0;
    for(var i=0 ; i<d.childNodes.length ; i++)
    {
     if( d.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1)
    {
      ++pCounter;
    }
    if( pCounter == 2)
    {
      alert("i= " + i + " object= "+d.childNodes[i]);
      alert("second paragraph before " + d.childNodes[i].innerHTMl);
      d.childNodes[i].innerHTMl = "paragraph4";
      alert("second paragraph after " + d.childNodes[i].innerHTMl);
      break;
    }

   }

  </script>
```

When i display the resualt using `alert(second paragraph before " + d.childNodes[i].innerHTMl)`, why is undefined displayed instead of `"paragraph2"`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo `innerHTMl` -> `innerHTML` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp.

Identifiers are case sensitive

Comment: Isn't `innerHTML` a property not a variable? *update:* come to think of it the *"w3schools"* documentation you have linked clearly states "innerHTML property"

Comment: Very welcome. Although your post does fix the problem I didn't want it to mislead people or confuse variables with properties. Thank you for updating your post.